# Wix Velo Database Query Has No Results

Tags: json, database, velo

I am attempting to query my database called battery2221 but keep getting no results. I've read all the API documentation but can't seem to find the problem. Any feedback is greatly appreciated.  Here is my page code:

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';

$w.onReady(function () {
    //TO DO: Write Your Page Related Code Here:

})

export function button1_click(event, $w) {
    //Add your code for this event here:
    getVINInfo($w("#vininput").value)
        .then(VINInfo => {
                console.log(VINInfo)

                let year = VINInfo.Results[9].Value;
                let make = VINInfo.Results[6].Value;
                let model = VINInfo.Results[8].Value;
                let engine = VINInfo.Results[71].Value + " " + "Liters"
                let car = VINInfo.Results[9].Value + "  " + VINInfo.Results[6].Value + "  " + VINInfo.Results[8].Value;

                wixData.query("battery2221")
                    .include("title")
                    .eq("year", year)
                    .eq("make", make)
                    .eq("model", model)
                    .find()
                    .then((results) => {
                            console.log(results);

                            $w("#results").text = "Vehicle Specific Battery for Your" + " " + car;
```

Here is what the developers console shows when I run the code:

```
_query: 
{...}
jsonTableCopy JSON

orderBy: 
"undefined"

invalidArguments: 
[...]

filterTree: 
{...}
jsonTableCopy JSON

$and: 
Array(3)
jsonTableCopy JSON

0: 
{...}
jsonTableCopy JSON

year: 
"2019"

1: 
{...}
jsonTableCopy JSON

make: 
"HONDA"

2: 
{...}
jsonTableCopy JSON

model: 
"Civic"
{
  "$and": [
    {
      "year": "2019"
    },
    {
      "make": "HONDA"
    },
    {
      "model": "Civic"
    }
  ]
}
```

This code has worked when the Wix language was Corvid but since switching to Velo the code no longer functions.

What I need is to query the battery2221 database for the year, make and model from the VINInfo results. The result should be the battery reference field (field name is “title” in the database) from the database.

Any and all feedback is appreciated

Comment: This may no longer be a question for which you are seeking an answer; if you found a solution, please feel free to answer your own question. I'm seeking an answer myself and your question came up in my search, but it seems that everybody has fully ignored it.